# Changed backend to use SSL, and our SSL is not working. I need to change it back but cannot access now

Tags: magento, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Yesterday, I went into my Magento backend.  I went under System>Configuration>Web and changed it to access the backend through secure (Https) connection.  However, our SSL is not working, and now I cannot get back in there to change it back.  I have read some answers where people are saying to use phpmyadmin to access some files to change.  However I am not able to access phpmyadmin. I have downloaded and installed it on the server, but when I go to mysite/phpmyadmin, it says that the URL is not available on the server?  Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need access you MySQL database using phpMyAdmin, MySQL workbench or [command line](http://www.linux.org/article/view/create-mysql-database-via-command-line), and modify your `core_config_data` table

To view

```
select * from core_config_data where path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

To update

```
UPDATE core_config_data
SET value = 'http://www.example.com'
WHERE value = 'https://www.example.com'
```

or

```
UPDATE core_config_data
SET value = 'http://www.example.com'
where path = 'web/secure/base_url'
```

Take a look @ [Update Site URL in core_config_data after you move to a new server or change domains](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/update_site_url_in_core_config_data)

Comment: How do I access that?  Im Sorry, Im learning all of this as I go.  I have Mysql Workbench on my server, can I access that through there?

Comment: Yes using MyPHPAdmin MySQL workbench or command line, see my updated answer

Comment: I have MySql Workbench, but do not know how to use it to access the DB?

Comment: I watched the video.  It shows how to install MySql Workbench.  However, I already have it installed.  I can pull up the schemas, but have no idea how to pull up the database info to edit?

Comment: Do you see your magento db?

Comment: yes. I finally found what you were talking about.  Thank you very much.  And changed the things that needed to be changed. However, when I put in http://mystore, the computer is automatically trying to redirect to the secure https? and, therefore, still not allowing me into the admin area? I don't know if its a cache thing or what?

Comment: If cache is enable then you need to clear it (magento_root/var/cache).

Comment: I just did, and its working GREAT!  Thank You so much!  Cheers!